# Does opengl performs Visibilty algorithms based on z-index?

Tags: opengl

Does OpenGL performs Visibilty algorithms based on z-index? Or we have to write our own algorithms. Mainly I'm referring to z-buffer algorithm. Is it in-built?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, OpenGL (or really, the GPU hardware that OpenGL is used to access) has built-in support for depth testing via z-buffers.  To enable it, you just have to ensure your OpenGL context includes a depth buffer when it's created (the details of this depend on what OS or toolkit you're using).  Then, insert these calls in your render function prior to drawing any geometry:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
glClearDepth(1.0f);
```

and add `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` to your `glClear` call.  That should be all you need to do to enable z-buffering.  For more information, see [this tutorial](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Positioning/Tut05%20Overlap%20and%20Depth%20Buffering.html).